# TinyMCE 4 - Select multiple elements and set style

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am facing a weird tinymce issue,

When I select multiple element inside editor and try to set their style (like font family, font color, font size..) then it just applied a single to a single word where the cursor is or nothing happen.

Like, this are elements inside my editor:

```
<p>Vestibulum vestibulum velit nec Ut nec leo tellus.</p>    
<p>Nunc in metus sit amet eu ante risus.</p>     
<strong>In ultrices parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</strong>
```

If I try to set style multiple selecting this three, then it wont work, happen with every elemnt.

But, I select texts inside single element then it works fine.

This issue also occur in official demo page: [Official demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php)

Comment: can you desribe axactly what a user needs to to in order to reproduce this behavior? (step by step)

Comment: My problem was solved, when I added 20px padding to editor, probably it was selecting the content which are outside inline editor. Anyway thanks

Comment: in this case you should answer your own question and accept it after two days